# Do we need a canonical question on "Statement of Purpose"?

Tags: discussion

I am finding many questions on the site relating to what should be included and omitted in a *Statement of Purpose* (SoP) for doctoral admissions.

I think that many people are confused. They want to either brag about their past accomplishments or make excuses for past failures. Some want to talk about how their special circumstances have disadvantaged them.

My own view, frequently stated, seldom downvoted, is that the SoP should be entirely forward looking, giving goals for study and thereafter. Short statements (phrases) of how their past makes success in attaining those goals are fine, but not the basis of the statement.

I also recommend that others (letter writers) be encouraged to state those other things (overcoming failure, wild success) that are more believable (IMO) when stated by third parties than by candidates themselves. Likewise, I recommend that past accomplishments be in the CV, not the SoP.

There seem to be two different kinds of SoP, just as there are two different kinds of doctoral programs. In the US, the program usually doesn't require that the candidate come to the process with a plan for research and so the SoP is very general.

In some other places, it is expected as part of the application process, perhaps to a PI, that the candidate already have a pretty firm proposal for their research. In such places an SoP might, instead, ask specific questions such as how the candidate's background supports that research and how they intend to carry out their plan.

Should we have a canonical question giving advice on such things? If so, what should it include/exclude? There might be more than one canonical answer to this question, depending on the sort of program it applies to.

I'll wait a bit to make content suggestions in an answer.